# Jmeter: How to save jtl logs in parts in non-gui mode

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, java-websocket

I'm getting result in GBs under jtl files, so how I can save jtl files in parts so that I can delete older files during Jmeter run.

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -j D:\jmeter.log -l D:\jmeterJTL.jtl
```

Above command will save the jmeter.log and jmeterJTL.jtl file in directory (D:). But I'm getting 1 gb data in 1 hour so how I can save this in parts: jmeter1.log jmeter2.log jmeter3.log ... and jmeterJTL1.jt1 jmeterJTL2.jt1 jmeterJTL3.jt1 ...

Note: I'm also saving result in .jtl to logged in thread name so that I can debug. Is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are writing more response data (might be whole response data). You can reduce the file size by configuring the below properties.

In your `jmeter.properties` or `user.properties` file, use the following:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
```

You can check [this blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) blog to learn more about how to tune the performance of JMeter.

Comment: using log4j we can do it in java like MaxFileSize=100mb and backupIndex=5so it it will keep only 5 file each of 100mb and delete the old one. Do we have the similar thing in jmeter????

Comment: By configuring below property you can limit/extend the bytes.

# Max size of bytes stored in memory per SampleResult
# Ensure you don't exceed max capacity of a Java Array and remember 
# that the higher it is, the higher JMeter will consume heap
# Defaults to 10MB

`httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request=10485760`